# Local maximum of a two dimensional function, knowing its second derivative

Tags: calculus

Can we know for certain that a function $f(x,y)$ **does not** have a local maximum at some point $p$ if we know that $\frac{∂^2f}{∂^2x}(p)>0$?

Comment: Do you mean the partial derivative by $x$?

Comment: Yes! Is that not how people write that?

Comment: Not exactly, it's usually denoted with $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}\text{ or }\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f$$

Comment: Yes, because $p + \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$ is a point that is larger than $p$ by definition of 2nd derivative.

Comment: You have to give more details: is $f$ a twice continuously differentiable real-valued function defined on an open set of $\mathbb R^2$?